# Python/Plone: Getting all unique keywords (Subject)

Tags: python, plone, keyword, subject

Is there a way of getting all the unique keyword index i.e. Subject in Plone by querying the catalog?

I have been using [this](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searching_and_indexing/query.html) as a guide but not yet successful.

This is what I have so far

```
def search_content_by_keywords(self):
    """
    Attempting to search the catalog
    """
    catalog = self.context.portal_catalog
    query = {}
    query['Subject'] = 'Someval'        

    results = catalog.searchResults(query)
    return results
```

Instead of passing the keyword, I want to fetch all the keywords

Comment: It's good practice to give some code and example input/output. People are way more likely to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
catalog = self.context.portal_catalog
my_keys = catalog.uniqueValuesFor('Subject')
```

reference: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/query.html#unique-values